# RPi 2 CPU constantly at 100%

Tags: cpu

I have a rpi3  and a rpi2 they are both running stretch. However my Rpi2 constantly stays at 100% CPU. It is also extremely slow executing commands from the terminal. I am using all 4 USB ports and camera on the rpi3 and it varies from 60% to 80%. The rpi2 is new I have had my rpi3  for over a year. Is this common? Can I do anything to decrease the CPU usage on the 2 for better performance?

Comment: You need to add some more information. Like the output of `top`.

Comment: I am not on my pi now so I can't screen shot what the out put of top said.However  I was trying to copy the SD card on to a USB flash drive. I ejected the USB stick and then it was not at a constant 100% CPU anymore. I will work on this later on today thank you